# how to reveal a liar user-agent

Tags: javascript, php

**If i change my user-agent with Javascript, are there any ways to reveal it with other languages like php?**

I changed user-agent with [this adds-on](http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/) (firefox)

and test it with FIrefox but with this parameter "Internet Explorer 8"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(navigator.userAgent);
</script>
```

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)

```
<?php
  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)

Comment: You can't.  As long as there's nothing obviously wrong with the user agent string I can make it say whatever I want and there's no reliable way for you to know otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Agent is the string send by the browser to the server. So there's no way, server side, to tell apart.

On way you *could* reveal it, it to prove a user support more client-sides feature that the browser he announces he has. But it could be fooled too... so, there's no SURE way.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can only access the User Agent String passed by the browser, so as far as it is a valid user agent string, there is no way to say if the user is using Explorer or he is just saying it is using that.